# Как сделать прокрутку QListWidget свайпом

Tags: android, c++, qt, виджет

Пытаюсь разобраться с Qt под Android. На форме размещен QListWidget, при этом привычная сенсорная прокрутка свайпом не работает.

Собсвтенно как реализовать прокрутку свайпом?

Файл проекта .pro:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = AndroidMainWindow
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY =
```

В .cpp только заполнение QListWidget больше никаких изменений

[image: QListWidget]
[image: QComboBox]

```
for( short i = 0; i < 50; i++ )
{
    QListWidgetItem * item = new QListWidgetItem();
    item->setSizeHint( QSize(0, 70) );
    item->setText( "Элемент списка номер " + QString::number(i) );
    ui->listWidget->addItem( item );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вначале обработку сенсора надо включить с помощью функции [QWidget::grabGesture](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grabGesture):

```
QListWidget * my_list = ...
my_list->grabGesture(Qt::SwipeGesture);
```

Второй вариант, использовать класс [QScroller](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscroller.html):

```
QScroller::grabGesture(my_list, QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);
```

Если QScroller не устраивает можно обрабатывать события от сенсора [QGestureEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgestureevent.html) самостоятельно (пример с doc.qt.io):

```
bool MyWidget::event(QEvent *event)
{
   if (event->type() == QEvent::Gesture)
       return gestureEvent(static_cast<QGestureEvent*>(event));
   return QWidget::event(event);
}

bool MyWidget::gestureEvent(QGestureEvent *event)
{
    if (QGesture *swipe = event->gesture(Qt::SwipeGesture))
       swipeTriggered(static_cast<QSwipeGesture *>(swipe));
    else if (QGesture *pan = event->gesture(Qt::PanGesture))
       panTriggered(static_cast<QPanGesture *>(pan));
    if (QGesture *pinch = event->gesture(Qt::PinchGesture))
       pinchTriggered(static_cast<QPinchGesture *>(pinch));

    return true;
}
```

[Более подробно обо всей кухне](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gestures-overview.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое, решение работает, но меня все же смущает что он так отображается, я слышал, что есть какие-то флаги, но нагуглить не смог.